# QProcess doesn't run with spaces in path

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I've run into a problem with starting a QProcess where the path contains spaces. The general goal is to run other program (at the moment on Windows, but macOS would be great, too). I tested multiple different paths and it seems that only paths without spaces work.

This works:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->startDetached("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera\\launcher.exe");
```

This doesn't work:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->startDetached("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
```

How can I get this working?
Any help is welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Edit:
based on the comment by vahancho, I tried the second example again and it worked. Thank you!
Will do more testing with multiple other paths and update this post.

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->startDetached("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\"");
```

Comment: Maybe so: `process->startDetached("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\"");`?

Comment: You, Sir! Are my hero! Will need more testing, but it seems to work now! Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, use the `setProgram` and `startDetached` methods to avoid quoting headaches.

Comment: can you elaborate? How would I use `setProgram`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set program and arguments separately Qt will figure out the correct quoting for you. Note the list of arguments, each will be exactly one argument in the target process:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->setProgram("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
process->setArguments(QStringList() << "www.google.com");
process->startDetached();
```